# How to convert cell vlookup to VBA

Tags: vba, excel, lookup-tables, vlookup

Currently, I am having a formula in my cell:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,'Daily Report'!A:Z,2,FALSE),"")

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,'Daily Report'!A:Y,7,FALSE)&", "&VLOOKUP(A:A,'Daily Report'!A:Y,8,FALSE)&", #"&VLOOKUP(A:A,'Daily Report'!A:Y,9,FALSE)&"-"&VLOOKUP(A:A,'Daily Report'!A:Y,10,FALSE)&", Singapore "&VLOOKUP(A:A,'Daily Report'!A:Y,11,FALSE),"")
```

How do I convert it to VBA so the entire column will be encrypted with this formula?

My formula is always replaced by the guys using my excel sheet.

I am avoiding locking  the cell, hence looking at VBA to perform this action.

Edited:

**MACRO**

```
Sub vlookup()
Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C[-3],'Daily Report'!C[-3]:C[22],2,FALSE),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Now how to make data e.g. 09-02-18022013-03383-A when enter to column A, it will run the macro to input the rightful data.

Comment: Why not just lock the cells if you are concerned about preserving the formulae? This seems to be the easiest way to control undesired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use VBA, the simplest way would be to just re-write the formula in the affected cells:

First, place this in the Worksheet's module. This will cause the macro to fire EVERY time a change is made to the column A.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
If Not Intersect(Target,Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False   'to disable infinite loop
    InsertFormula
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Then, place this in an ordinary code module:

```
Sub InsertFormula()
Dim rng as Range   'this will set the range in which you want this formula to appear
Dim cl as Range    'cell iterator within rng variable
Dim strFormula1 as String  `string to hold the formula text

set rng = Range("B2:B39")   'Change this range to the desired range
strFormula = "=IfError(Vlookup(A:A,'Daily Report'!A:Z,2,False),"")"

For Each cl in rng
    cl.Formula = strFormula
Next

End Sub
```

So, programmatically inserting a normal formula is fairly easy.

The question then becomes how often do you want to force/overwrite these cells? You can tie this macro to "events" like, whenever the workbook file is opened, or whenever a value on the sheet changes, or whenever someone manually changes the cells you don't want them to change, etc.

Your second formula you could do the same thing with it, just add another Range variable (e.g., `Dim rng2 as Range`) and another string variable to hold the formula text (e.g., `strFormula2`).

Alternatively, you could "rewrite the formula" purely in vba. Replace `cl.Formula = strFormula` with `cl.Value = MyLookupFormula` and add this function to the code module containing the subroutine above:

```
Function MyLookupFormula() as Variant
'Performs equivlanet to worksheet function
If Not IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("A:A"),Sheets("Daily Report").Range("A:Z"),2,False)) Then

myLookupFormula = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("A:A"),Sheets("Daily Report").Range("A:Z"),2,False))

Else: myLookupFormula = vbNullString
End Function
```

But that requires knowing more about how often/what events will trigger this macro, since the cells will not have any formula (the formula/computation is performed in memory ONLY when requested by user or an event trigger).

Comment: Thanks David. But how do I make it when Column A have value or is not blank, then it will run the following code?

Comment: The condition you describe can be further built in to the code above with a simple `If` statement -- for example you could change `cl.Formula = strFormula` to `If cl.Value <> "" Then cl.Formula = strFormula`, or from the second example, `If cl.Value <> "" Then cl.Value = MyLookupFormula`, but that is not sufficient instruction to CAUSE or initiate execution of the code. Code can be executed manually, or tied to "events".  The code I provide has to be executed manually because you have not indicated it should be an event-driven macro.

Comment: How to I make a event if  Column A have value or is not blank, then it will run the following code for Column B.

The formulae is for column B, but the primary key will be Column A to trigger it. 

Hence once there is value in Column A, it should run the code for Column B

Comment: You're still not describing an EVENT. You're describing a CONDITION.

Comment: See revision for event handling that will fire this macro EVERY time a change occurs in Column A.

Comment: Above amended copy is working for me by using recording macro. 

But still, the Worksheet_Change event unable to work. Whenever a new data entered, column D is still not updating.

Comment: Why don't you just lock the cells? It is pretty clear that you are not understanding the way that VBA functions and events work, and this will potentially do more harm than good.

Comment: Since you are unable to help me further, I will still say Thank you.

Comment: You say "Whenever a new data entered, column D is still not updating." This is because your macro is NOT associated with the Worksheet_Change event.